# Combine 2 fields in one div with Twig

Tags: theming, 8

I have three templates

1. field--field-custom.html.twig
2. field--field-custom1.html.twig
3. field--field-image.html.twig

I also have a teaser template containing all three fields like that:

```
<div{{ content_attributes.addClass('node__content', 'container') }}>
    {{ content }}
</div>
```

I want to have the first two templates in a bootstrap div, for example

```
col-sm-6
```

and the third template in the other div

```
col-sm-6
```

If I include the second template in the first template file it just repeats the field instead of rendering the intended field (both templates are name suggestions of the same file). 
What can I do in order to have both fields in the same template file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just chunk the output by using the field names:

`<div class=“col-6-sm”>{{ content.field_custom }} {{ content.field_custom1 }}</div>`

Then do the same for the remaining field.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you Kevin. I did it in the node--teaser-*  template and just realized, I don't need the field---field-* templates anymore. The first time I tried with the template names, but it refers to the field machine name.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div{{ content_attributes.addClass('node__content', 'container', 'col-sm-6') }}>
    {{ content.field_imagen }}
  </div>
  <div{{ content_attributes.addClass('node__content', 'container', 'col-sm-6') }}>
    {{ content.field_resumen }}
    {{ content.field_leer_mas }}
  </div>
```

Thanks to Kevin!